# Split array basing on chunk weight

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, approximation

I have an array with `2 <= n <= 100` doubles:

```
A = [a1, a2, ... , an], ai > 0
```

and an integer `2 <= k <= min(n, 20)`. I need to split `A` into `k`  subarrays:

```
B1 = [a1,     a2, ... , ap]
B2 = [ap+1, ap+2, ... , aq]

             ...

Bk = [aw+1, aw+2, ... , an]
```

such that the sum in each `B` is *almost equal* (it's hard to give a strict definition what this means - I'm interested in an approximate solution).

Example:

```
Input: A = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1], k=2
Output: [[1, 2, 1], [2, 1]] or [[1, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
```

I tried a probabilistic approach:

- sample from `[1, 2, .., n]` using `A` as probability weights
- cut the sample into quantiles to find a good partition,

but this was not stable enough for production.

**tl;dr** This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602338/split-array-to-approximately-equal-chunks) asks about 2-chunk divisions. I need `k`-chunk division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate overall sum of array `S`. Every chunk sum should be near `S / K`.

Then walk through array, calculating running sum `R`. When `R+A[i+1] - S/K` becomes larger than `S/K - R`, close current chunk and make `R=0`. Continue with the next chunk.

You also can compensate accumulating error (if it occurs), comparing overall sum of `M` chunks with `M * S / K`

Quick-made code for the last approach (not thoroughly checked)

```
def chunks(lst, k):
    s = sum(lst)
    sk = s / k
    #sk = max(s / k, max(lst))
    #variant from user2052436 in comments  
    idx = 0
    chunkstart = 0
    r = 0
    res = []
    for m in range(1, k):
        for idx in range(chunkstart, len(lst)):
            km = k -m
            irest = len(lst)-idx
            if((km>=irest) or (2*r+lst[idx]>2*m*sk)) and (idx>chunkstart):
                res.append(lst[chunkstart:idx])
                chunkstart = idx
                break
            r += lst[idx]
    res.append(lst[idx:len(lst)])
    return res

print(chunks([3,1,5,2,8,3,2], 3))
print(chunks([1,1,1,100], 3))

>>>[[3, 1, 5], [2, 8], [3, 2]]
   [[1, 1], [1], [100]]
```

Comment: Thank you for a nice snippet! The problem with this approach is that sometimes it fails - for example `chunks([1, 1, 1, 100], 3)` will return 2 subarrays, not 3.

Comment: Yes, we have to add limit for chunk length (account for `k-m` and `len-idx` comparison)

Comment: Made this correction. Perhaps there are another hard cases.

Comment: This seems to work very well, great job! (I haven't created a test making this fail)

Comment: Unfortunately such a hard case exists:
`chunks([16, 8, 6, 4], 4)` returns `[[16], [], [8], [6, 4]]`

Comment: Logic mistake in algorithm - empty chunk added when accumulated sum is too high. Will check.

Comment: Added check for empty chunk.

Comment: Passes all the tests I invented!

Comment: Is there any proof for this approach?

Comment: @Pham Trung No, just arbitrary chosen and adapted heuristics.

Comment: Does not work well for `print(chunks([100,1,1,103,90], 3))`. Result: `[[100], [1, 1, 103], [90]]`.

Comment: `sk = max(s / k, max(lst))` fixes above example: result `[[100, 1, 1], [103], [90]]`

Comment: @ser2052436 But probably might give worse variant in some cases (did not tested). See also Pham Trung solution in linked topic

Comment: It should not give worse variants: usually (especially when `n >> k`), `s / k is > max(lst)`, so your average stays. If there is a huge outlier, then chunk containing the outlier will have a sum at least equal to this outlier, so it makes sense to use the outlier instead of the average.