# Split array into sub-arrays of similar weight

Tags: algorithm, optimization, load-balancing, mathematical-optimization

I have an array of `n` positive numbers. I need to split it into `N` contiguous sub-arrays; `n > N`.

I need to minimize `[max S(j) over j] - [min S(j) over j]`,
where `S(j)` denotes sum of elements in `j-th` sub-array, `(j = 1,...,N)`.

I.e., all sub-arrays should have "same" sum of elements.

I am sure this problem is known.. Could someone point me to algorithms, implementations, or publications?

Comment: Quick (linear algorithm) approximation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094356/

Comment: @MBo Thanks. I wonder, if it is NP-hard to solve my problem exactly...

Comment: Pham Trung approach seems reasonable

Comment: @MBo No, it does not work: see my comment to his post

Answer (score 1):

This problem is equivalent to finding the min of `max S(j) over all j`.

Intuition:

- Assume that the minimum of all possible `max S(j) over all j` is `xmax`, so the result will be `xmax - xmin`.
- Assume that, another `ymax > xmax` that could provide us a better result, which means `ymax - ymin` < `xmax - xmin` -> `ymin > xmin` -> `min S(j) - ymax` > `min S(j) - xmax`, which should not happen.

So, the problem point down to finding the min of `max S(j) over all j`

This can be solved by using binary search.
Assuming that the total sum of the whole array is `X`, so we have our algo:

```java
int start = 0;
int end = X;
int result = 0;
while(start <= end){
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       if sum of current segment > mid
           split

    }
    if total segment > N
       start = mid + 1;
    else 
       update result;
       end = mid - 1;
}
```

Comment: I disagree. Consider split of `[10 7 3 4]` into 3 sub-arrays. Looking for `min` of `max` gives 2 equivalent answers: `10 | 7 3 | 4` and `10 | 7 | 3 4`. Looking for `min` of `max - min` gives only one best answer: `10 | 7 | 3 4`

Answer (score 0):

Find the sum of the whole array and call that `T`, and do `k = T / N` to determine the ideal sum of the first sub-array's elements. Then create the first sub-array linearly (starting from the start of the array) while trying to minimise the difference between `k` and `sum of all values in the sub-array so far + potential next element` when deciding if the sub-array should/shouldn't include the next element.

Then use recursion to split the remaining part of the array into `N-1` pieces, stopping when `N == 1` (the remaining part of the array is the last sub-array).

*Note: This doesn't give the optimal solution in all cases, but it is relatively fast and for the purpose of (dynamic) load balancing there's a risk that loads will change so often that anything more expensive (that does always find the optimal solution) is pointless.*